# Insert rows into table based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to have a macro add in a specific number of rows to a table based on the value of A2.

For example:

If A2=10, then when I run the macro it should insert 10 rows.

also, as a second part to the macro I want it to copy the formula that the previous cells have.

Example:

```
A3= "='Sheet2'!A1"
```

and if I add 10 rows then the following rows should be sequential:

```
A4= "='Sheet2'!A1"
A5= "='Sheet2'!A2"
A6= "='Sheet2'!A3"
A7= "='Sheet2'!A4"
A8= "='Sheet2'!A5"
```

etc...

I know that a typical drag of the table will copy the cells, I want to ensure that the formula's are copied to the next row.

Comment: So you want to insert **10** rows but only **5** formulas ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will copy and paste the formula as you showed in A3 down the number you enter in A2.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells.Range("A4:A" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1).Value
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(3 + i, 1).Formula = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(3, 1).FormulaR1C1
Next i
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Works like a charm! I have a secondary question to go with it.

Is there a way to use the "i" in a range selection formula? What I would like to be able to do is clear the contents for the cells that were there previously, so if there were 10 cells before and now there are 8, then it would clear out the extra two...hopefully that made sense.

Comment: @user1664305 updated my answer, use ClearContents as per my new edit to my answer. Don't forget to give a thumbs up!